# How to trigger a Javascript function on folder creation in SharePoint Library?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, item-level-permissions

I want to grant unique permission on folder level in SharePoint 2013 Library , Once a new folder is created, edit permission should be granted to the one who has created it.

I've been using the following code the grant permission, which is working fine.

```
 function readPermisiontoUSER(id,email) 
    
    {  

      Context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
      var Website = Context.get_web();   
      var oList = Context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('my_Lib');
      var ListItem = oList.getItemById(id);
           
  
    ListItem.breakRoleInheritance(false);  
    this.User = Context.get_web().get_siteUsers().getByEmail(email);  

    var collRoleDefinitionBinding = SP.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection.newObject(Context);  
    
    collRoleDefinitionBinding.add(Context.get_web().get_roleDefinitions().getByType(SP.RoleType.editor));    
    ListItem.get_roleAssignments().add(User, collRoleDefinitionBinding);   
    Context.load(User);  
    Context.load(ListItem);  
    Context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  

}  
  
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {  
  
    console.log('Role inheritance broken for item ');  
        
}  
  
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) 

{  
  
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());  
}
```

Now the issue is, i need to trigger this JavaScript function immediately when a new folder is created, is there any easy to achieve this ?

Comment: Did you look at the option of setting the Item level permissions, I think "Create items and edit items that were created by the user" permission is what you need. See https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-enable-item-level-permissions-in-sharepoint/

Comment: maybe event receivers or SharePoint designer workflow are more proper ways to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create **SharePoint Designer workflow 2010** to achieve your design.

**Please follow steps:**

1.Go to your Library and click on "**Edit library**" to open SharePoint Designer 2013
[image]

2.Create a SharePoint 2010 Workflow named "Grant Permission"

3.Click on **Impersonation Step** in the ribbon menu to insert Impersonation Step before **Step 1**.
[image]

4.Under the Impersonation Step, click on **Condition** and choose **If current item field equals value** from the drop down menu.
[image]
5.Next click on the **Action** button on the ribbon, scroll down to the **List Actions** section and choose **Inherit List Item Parent Permissions**, and then choose **Replace List Item Permissions**.
[image]

6.Under the **Step 1**, click on the **Action** button on the ribbon, scroll down to the **List Actions** section and choose **Update List Items**
[image]

7.**Save** and **Publish** this workflow.
[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing this idea, it worked and saved  me a lot of time . thanks you so much

Comment: Hi, Jegan Baskaran. Glad I can help you. Have a nice day!